# How to post view model to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am trying to create a view that takes a view model, simply has an int property and a list of child model, with int; string; string properties.

What i am trying to do is everytime user clicks an "add line" button, i am creating a new child model in my view model list, letting user edit the properties and then want to post back to my controller but no matter what, it is always empty.

I know this must be simple but has me stumped for hours today? Is there some magic that needs to happen?

Any help appreciated.

My Controller:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeUploadController : Controller
    {
        // GET: EmployeeUpload
        public ActionResult EmployeeUpload()
        {
            var vm = new EmployeeBulkUpload { UploadedBy = 12345 };
            vm.Employees.Add(new EmployeeBulkUploadItem { Id = 1, JobTitle = "Labourer", Name = "Jimmy" });
            return View(vm);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("EmployeeUpload")]
        public ActionResult EmployeeUploadPost(EmployeeBulkUpload vm)
        {

            return View(vm);
        }
    }
}
```

My Model:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class EmployeeBulkUpload
    {
        public EmployeeBulkUpload()
        {
            Employees = new List<EmployeeBulkUploadItem>();
        }
        public int UploadedBy { get; set; }
        public List<EmployeeBulkUploadItem> Employees { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmployeeBulkUploadItem
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string JobTitle { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My "Container" view:

```
@using WebApplication1.Models
@model WebApplication1.Models.EmployeeBulkUpload
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EmployeeUpload";
}<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("EmployeeUpload", "EmployeeUpload", FormMethod.Post))
    {
    <h2>EmployeeUpload</h2>
    <button>Add New</button>

    foreach(EmployeeBulkUploadItem emp in Model.Employees)
    {
        Html.RenderPartial("_EmployeeUploadItem", emp);
    }

    <input type="submit" name="SaveButton" value="Save" />
    }
</div>
```

My Item Partial view:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.EmployeeBulkUploadItem
<li>
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Id)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Id)
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.JobTitle)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.JobTitle)
</li>
```

I can load with one record and post straight back but is always empty in my Controller EmployeeUploadPost method?

Comment: It will be hard to help without the code. Just like that, it should work.

Comment: Can you show the code where it is always null, also how you are posting it

Comment: i think what you are trying to do is to post complex models, building a list on view end and posting it in controller will require the right type of model binding. if you can show what you have done it will help us to provide with right suggestion